# UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no essfet. Use 'with torch.no_grad():' insted

Tags: python, pytorch, volatile, user-warning

The version of PyTorch: 1.4.0+cu100
When running

```
val_L= Variable(torch.from_numpy(val_L.copy()), volatile=True).cuda()
```

occurred：

```
UserWarning: volatile was removed and now has no essfet. Use 'with torch.no_grad():' insted.
```

So, how should I modify the code?
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I modified the code to the following form:

with torch.no_grad():
    val_L = torch.from_numpy(val_L.copy()).cuda
Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

this is what it is referring to

```
with torch.no_grad():
    val_L= Variable(torch.from_numpy(val_L.copy()))
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this：
with torch.no_grad():
    val_L= Variable(torch.from_numpy(val_L.copy())).cuda()